# Bash return stderr of the first failed process

Tags: bash, redirection

I need to run some commands and if any of those fails I would like to output JSON with it's stderr.

I have the following line:

```
OUT="$( (ssh internal "custom_script1" | custom_app1 2>&- | custom_script2) 2>&1)"
```

If the pipeline is broken, every command will write onto its stderr and OUT will have 2 lines. 
How can I know which command causes the failure and grab stderr of that command?

Let's say that I am unable to ssh to internal, so I want to print SSH stderr only:

```
{
  "state": "failed",
  "reason": "Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood this correctly, just avoid the global 2>1.

```
$ OUT="$( (ssh internal "custom_script1" | cut -f 1 2>&- | cut -f 2 2>&1) )"
ssh: Could not resolve hostname internal: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
$ echo $OUT
$
```